# How to disable changing of orientations in iOS 5.1.1 after rotation?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

I would like to know how to disable Portrait and UpsideDown orientations in my app for iOS 5.1.1. 
I want my app to use only  LandScape orientation  (interface was drawn in Interface Build in .xib file) and don't change it in case of rotation.
I need it especially for iOS 5.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question: [how do you make an app ONLY support landscape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838459/how-do-you-make-an-app-only-support-landscape)

This method was used in the answer above:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        return YES;

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in project settings. In xCode 5 you open the project navigator, click on your project, click on the general tab, and check the boxes you want.